# Adding icons to nativemenu items in air application

Tags: flex3, air, icons, native, menuitem

I have a native menu with items and it is displayed as a pop up menu, i would like to add icons to the native menu items in an air application using flex3. How can i do that?
Thanks in advance.
bagi

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple logic:

1) You can access core properties, like `icon` or `iconField` look http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/24/displaying-icons-in-a-flex-popupbutton-control/
http://amarghosh.blogspot.com/2010/01/icons-in-flex-menubar.html

or

2) Override itemRenderer with your own, and set up images via data node, e.g. http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/25/creating-a-custom-combobox-item-renderer-in-flex/

Comment: those links actually showing the button thing...the display shud appear just like a label, if u click on it, it shud provide with a dropdown or popup menu...how to customize the appearance of it.provide me sample code.

Comment: Do you mean replace button with just a Label?